# Windows How to change or insert physical sector into another file?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ntfs

I have 20 files where the data structure is sector aligned to 4k in NTFS. I want to combine all files **without copying any data**. 
The goal is to write a sort of insert API that works by directly changing NTFS Virtual Clusters and Physical Clusters.

The goal is to have a file sized 1TB all from 50GB chunks without copying. All data is already on the disk and on the same volume. 
This would work by directly setting the NTFS logical cluster inside the file.

I can read the Virtual to Physical translation of the files with **FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS**

Source: VCN: 0 Cluster: 16 LCN: 54723798

Target: VCN: 0 Cluster: 160 LCN: 6172145

I tried to use the Windows Defrag API:

```
bool fResult = DeviceIoControl(
                hVol,
                FSCTL_MOVE_FILE,
                p,
                bufSize,
                NULL, 
                0,
                ref size,
                NULL);
```

While this would be the perfect command for this, it cannot change the Physical adress of my source file to the physical adress of the target file: 
**STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED**. If I delete the Target file I can move the Physical Clusters, but the Target file is gone.

NTFS hard links would be good but I cannot create a hardlink to a subsection of another file.

I have administrator priviledges on the windows machine and I need to do this on the file system level not with the windows file API to avoid any copying. A solution would be to change the clusters by directly writing to the NTFS Master File Table.

Or by deleting the big file, changing all logical sectors of the 20 files to the deleted file sectors and then creating a file with specific already existing sectors.

---

A working solution would yield the result:

Source1: VCN: 0 Cluster: 16 LCN: 54723798

Source2: VCN: 0 Cluster: 16 LCN: 6172145

Target:

Extends 2:

VCN: 0 Cluster: 16 LCN: 54723798

VCN: 16 Cluster: 16 LCN: 6172145

---

To validate a change you can run a cmd windows as admin:

**fsutil volume filelayout "C:\Data\BigFile.txt"**

Any other idea or some C++/C code to change or insert a MFT entry would be welcome.

Update 1: I can read the MFT of the NTFS partition, but i really need someone who knows how to create or edit a fileentry. Other solutions are also welcome

Comment: C or C++? Please choose one. They're very different languages.

Comment: I can work with any working answer.

Comment: I think the only realistic way of doing this would be to dismount the volume and edit the raw disk contents directly.  I gather there's an open-source NTFS file system driver for Linux that might be helpful.

Comment: `FSCTL_MOVE_FILE` let move file clusters only to free space. and main - you say that **combine all files without copying any data** but **`FSCTL_MOVE_FILE** do the opposite - it **copy** data sectors - from old location to new. despite the *MOVE* keyord (and from file view this is move) - it copy - read file clusters and write it to free space clusters

Comment: FSCTL_MOVE_FILE just copy clusters, when you need change ownership information about clusters..

Comment: Guys its really simple: I need to edit the physical sector entries in the MFT entry for the file. I know that FSCTL_MOVE_FILE does not work. I need someone to point me in the right direction! 
**These things are normally handled by the OS so there must be a kernel32 invokation that does exactly what I need!**

SOME MAGIC METHOD THAT CAN CHANGE THE LCN ENTRY IN MFT PLEASE!

Comment: *Why* must there be a kernel32 invocation that does what you need?  The OS never needs to do that, and doesn't expect you to want to, either.  What you're trying to do is just really really weird.  (Which isn't to say that it is *necessarily* impossible, but it isn't *necessarily* possible, either.)

Comment: ... I suppose a file system filter driver might be able to write directly into the MFT.  It should certainly be possible for a file system filter driver to define a new type of reparse point that acts as if is was a file that contained the data from other files.

Comment: Microsoft have Data dedublication feature in server 2012 and 2016. You can google for it implementation. Of course, it have filter file system driver as part of it

Comment: Ok I can read the MFT but how can i edit the physical Sektor entry?

Comment: @MaxPayne you need to study how ntfs mtf works and do the job your self, i once saw a c code  in stackoverflow (dont't have link now) to insert bytes in to middle of a file without overwrting existing data, i bet the code can help you, as others pointed out you can study ntfs from opensource linux drive ntfs-3g