# How to merge two files on NTFS by chaining the file's B-tree nodes to avoid reading any file

Tags: api, file, merge, ntfs, b-tree

I have the following challenge:

- File1 is a huge file, let's say the the filesystem assigns it disk blocks [1, 2, 5]
- File2 is another huge file, let's say the filesystem assigns it disk blocks [**10, 15, 16, 18**]

Traditional append opens File2 and copies it to the end of File1, so it ends up like

- File1: [1, 2, 5], [*30, 20, 40, 182*] (it assigns and copies File2 blocks in new ones)
- File2: [**10, 15, 16, 18**] (Will still be in use and assigned to File2)

I want to merge the two files without ever reading the files, let's say, getting File1 chain and consume File2, so it ends like up

- File1: [1, 2, 5], [**10, 15, 16, 18**] (and File2 gets consumed in the process)

Do you know any API call to do that magic?

Comment: related: [Windows How to change or insert physical sector into another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44347459/995714)